# Core Graphics effect: works on simulator but not in device

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, core-graphics, core-image

I have done a simple but effective emboss effect with Core Graphics.
It works great! But only in simulator...
Here is the result:

[image: 1st image]

What I do is the following:
- From a picked image, I take the alpha out if it has and I fill it with white.
- I transform this RGB image to Grayscale
- I invert colors of this image

I then call a custom method to create the effect with parameters:

- canvasImg: a semi-transparent image to mask on
- maskImg: the image I just created, grayscale and inverted:

[image: 2nd image]

- opacitity: the opacity of the resulting image

The method then makes a simple mask, applies shadows and oppacity and returns a brand new UIImage.
I can't understand why in the simulator it does work, nor the device.
While running in the device, I get a non-null UIImage tho...
Please help!

Here is the code:

```
- (UIImage *)stampImage:(UIImage *)canvasImg withMask:(UIImage *)maskImg withOpacity:(CGFloat)opacity
{
//Creating the mask Image
CGContextRef mainViewContentContext;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
mainViewContentContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, maskImg.size.width, maskImg.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

if (mainViewContentContext == NULL) return NULL;

CGContextClipToMask(mainViewContentContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, maskImg.size.width, maskImg.size.height), maskImg.CGImage);
CGContextDrawImage(mainViewContentContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, maskImg.size.width, maskImg.size.height), canvasImg.CGImage);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(mainViewContentContext, true);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(mainViewContentContext, true);
CGImageRef mainViewContentBitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(mainViewContentContext);
CGContextRelease(mainViewContentContext);
UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:mainViewContentBitmapContext];
CGImageRelease(mainViewContentBitmapContext);

//Giving some Drop shadows
CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef shadowContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, maskedImage.size.width + 10, maskedImage.size.height + 10,
                                                   CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskedImage.CGImage), 0, 
                                                   colourSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(shadowContext, CGSizeMake(0, -1), 1, [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.3].CGColor);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(shadowContext, true);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(shadowContext, true);
CGContextDrawImage(shadowContext, CGRectMake(0, 10, maskedImage.size.width, maskedImage.size.height), maskedImage.CGImage);
CGImageRef shadowedCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(shadowContext);
CGContextRelease(shadowContext);

UIImage *stampImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:shadowedCGImage];
CGImageRelease(shadowedCGImage);

return stampImg;
```

}

Comment: What result do you see on the device?

Comment: If you're simply getting `nil` back, have you verified that `mainViewContentContext` is not `NULL`? It's possible the allowed inputs to `CGBitmapContextCreate()` are different on desktop vs device

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I dind't think about CGBitmapContextCreate(), it might be the problem. I will take a look on it.

Comment: In the device I got an empty UIImage, but it ain't nil.

Comment: Could it be `shadowContext`? You're not testing for `NULL` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also be aware of the memory limitations of the device vs the simulator.  I've had CG logic that would build and run fine on the simulator; the same logic will build and run emitting no errors on the device, but the visual result is not the desired one.  I'd suggest trying your logic on a considerably smaller image to verify that it works on the device.  I had to abandon some very cool image masking stuff that I'd come up with because the device didn't have the horsepower to pull it off for larger images.

Comment: Bingo!
For the first time it wasn't the code but the canvas image.
So I just made a new image, semi-transparent, grayscale and everything worked on the device!

Thank you Kevin and jstevenco for your replies :P